# no map receive, Gmappping with Velodyne HDL-32E

Tags: navigation, mapping, rviz, 2d-mapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All!!

I really need your help!

I am trying to make a map using “Gmapping” package, however I could not receive  any map data from it.

To make 3D scan data to 2D, I use but_velodyne_proc, then /odom date seem to be published correctly over /tf topics.

Also I checked  /tf frame, then it seems fine.
/velodyne(scan frame)-->/base_link-->/odom-->/map

But if I tried to visualize a map with rviz, they said "no map received" and "No tranceform [] to [map]"

I am new to ROS.
Thank you for your time and I will appreciate any help!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210612/no-map-receive,-gmappping-with-velodyne-hdl-32e/) by [Tomoko](https://answers.ros.org/users/22661/tomoko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-06-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tomoko](https://answers.ros.org/users/22661/tomoko/) on 2015-06-08**:
Thank you very much, Horse-man!
It worked, However I had another problem the odom data jumped a lot,,,,then not making a proper map. Anyway it is another thing, I will open a new question, Thank you again.

**Comment by [Horse-man](https://answers.ros.org/users/22198/horse-man/) on 2015-06-10**:
you're welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you specify the fixed frame in rviz ? To set the fixed frame see the section Global Options in the left panel. Generally we choose either /base_link or /map frame as a fixed frame.

---

Originally posted by [Horse-man](https://answers.ros.org/users/22198/horse-man/) with karma: 229 on 2015-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nunuwin](https://answers.ros.org/users/42390/nunuwin/) on 2019-06-11**:
I also the same condition "no map received" but I fixed frame in rviz? How can I check what is wrong?